# How to skip multiple iterations in a while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, streamreader, continue

I'm reading a text file line by line in a While loop. When I reach a specific line I want to skip the the current and the next 3 iterations.

I guess I can do it using a counter and things like that. But I was wondering if there is a more elegant way?

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(source))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line == "Section 1-1")
        {
            // skip the next 3 iterations (lines)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply execute ReadLines 3 times in your if clause, checking for null each time

Comment: @HugoRune Thanks, now this is what I meant by elegant.

Comment: Just read 3 more lines but don't use those lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a `for` loop to execute `sr.ReadLine` 3 times and discard the result like:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(source))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line == "Section 1-1")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should check for `sr.ReadLine` returning `null` or if the stream has come to an end.

Comment: Thanks Habib, this is the simple and elegant answer I was looking for. I guess I won't need to check for `null` in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `File.ReadAllLines` with method extesions:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SkipLines(string file, string line, int count)
{
    var enumerable = File.ReadLines(file).GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerable.MoveNext())
    {
        var currentLine = enumerable.Current;
        if (currentLine == line)
        {
            var currentCount = 0;
            while(enumerable.MoveNext() && currentCount < count) 
            {
                  currentCount += 1;
            }
        }

        yield return currentLine;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
foreach (var line in SkipLines(source, "Section 1-1", 3))
{
   // your line
}
```

Keep in mind: `ReadLines` is lazy - not all lines are loaded into memory at once.

Comment: Thanks pwas, Is this faster than `ReadLine()`? My text file is bit huge. Around 100,000 lines.

Comment: Where are you getting `MoveNext` from? I don't see it under a `string[]`.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks! I've put wrong method name - it is `ReadLines` not `ReadAllLines` :) +1 for you.

Comment: `MoveNext` is not under an IEnumerable (publicly at least) either.

Comment: `Keep in mind: ReadAllLines is lazy` No it's not.  `ReadLines` is lazy, `ReadAllLines` reads all of the lines.

Comment: @Servy yes - like gunr2171 noticed - I've got not a proper method.  gunr2171 - yeah - corrected, I've wrote that down from memory.

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself a function that discards a given number of lines (`DiscardLines`) and use it:

```
string line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line == "Section 1-1")
    {
        DiscardLines(sr, 3);
    }
}
```

That keeps the main loop very simple. The counter is now hidden in `DiscardLines`.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(source))
{
    string line;
    int linesToSkip = 0;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (linesToSkip > 0)
        {
            linesToSkip -= 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (line == "Section 1-1")
        {
            // skip the next 3 iterations (lines)
            linesToSkip = 3;
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zer0 for the answer, I +1 you, but as I stated in the question, I was trying to avoid a `counter`.